# How to mock imports with the node testing library?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocking

I'm trying to use the `node:test` library, and I would like to mock imported functions, like in [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks) example. The node library has [mocks](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html#mocking), but I couldn't make it work with imports. Does anyone have any idea? Maybe using [loaders](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders)?

Comment: it seems I found something here: https://github.com/coderaiser/mock-import

Comment: issue from nodejs github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/42242

Comment: currently this is not supported in the `node:test` API. there are a lot of libraries that will do what you're wanting though: [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon), [esmock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esmock), [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) and the ones you mentioned to name a few.